# OpenAI Gym ProcGen - Getting Action Meanings

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

In the OpenAI ProcGen gym, I am not getting a way **to get the meanings of the action values**, I can see that there are 15 actions for the coinrun environment using `env.action_space.n`. I have tried both the Gym and the Gym3 versions.

This is how I make the environment (gym version).

```py
env = gym.make('procgen:procgen-%s-v0'%('coinrun'))
```

Neither of these are working to seem to work.

```py
env.action_spec()
env.env.get_action_meanings()
```

I have tried to change `env` with `env.env` and `env.env.env`, nothing works. I get the message: `AttributeError: 'ToGymEnv' object has no attribute 'get_action_meanings'`.

Please tell me how I can get the labelled action list.

Object Types: `env` is a `ToGymEnv` object, `env.env` is , and `env.env.env` is `ProcgenGym3Env`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action meanings are hidden in the `get_combos` method in the `procgen.env`.

```
def get_combos(self):
    return [
        ("LEFT", "DOWN"),
        ("LEFT",),
        ("LEFT", "UP"),
        ("DOWN",),
        (),
        ("UP",),
        ("RIGHT", "DOWN"),
        ("RIGHT",),
        ("RIGHT", "UP"),
        ("D",),
        ("A",),
        ("W",),
        ("S",),
        ("Q",),
        ("E",),
    ]
```

To access them from an environment created in gym (`procgen==0.10.4`) you can use:

```
env = gym.make('procgen:procgen-%s-v0'%('coinrun'))
print(env.unwrapped.env.env.combos)
```

Which will result in:

```
[('LEFT', 'DOWN'), ('LEFT',), ('LEFT', 'UP'), ('DOWN',), (), ('UP',), ('RIGHT', 'DOWN'), ('RIGHT',), ('RIGHT', 'UP'), ('D',), ('A',), ('W',), ('S',), ('Q',), ('E',)]
```

In order to acces them from a `ProcgenEnv` use:

```
env = procgen.ProcgenEnv(env_name='maze', num_envs=1)
print(env.env.combos)
```